# Combining multiple JsResult with Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I'm looking for a way to combine multiple JsResult into one.
Here is my first try without using Shapeless

```
def combineJsResult[A,B](res1: JsResult[A], res2: JsResult[B]): JsResult[(A, B)] = (res1, res2) match {
    case (r1: JsError, r2: JsError) => r1 ++ r2
    case (JsSuccess(r1, _), JsSuccess(d, _)) => JsSuccess(r1 -> d)
    case (r1: JsError, _) => r1
    case (_, r2: JsError) => r2
  }
```

what I want is  a function taking n JsResult and combine them to a single JsResult[(A,B,C,...)]. Now I know the limitation of scala regarding abstracting over arity. 
I tried multiple codes with Shapeless but none of them compile because of JsResult being a type constructor and variance issue.
Here is the algorithm I have in my mind:

write a function taking an HList of JsResult of Any type as an argument.
foldRight on the list using JsSuccess(HNil) as the initial element and a variation of the above function (changing the result type to JsResult[HList]) as the folding function.

here is my final code (not compiling)

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsError, JsResult, JsSuccess}
import shapeless.{Generic, HList, HNil, Poly2}

object merger extends Poly2 {
  def apply = at{ (res1: JsResult[_], res2: JsResult[_]) => {
    (res1, res2) match {
      case (r1: JsError, r2: JsError) => r1 ++ r2
      case (JsSuccess(r1, _), JsSuccess(d, _)) => JsSuccess(r1 :: d :: HNil)
      case (r1: JsError, _) => r1
      case (_, r2: JsError) => r2
    }
  } }
}

def combineJsResults[P <: Product, L <: HList](p: P)(implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, L]) = {
  gen.to(p).foldRight[JsResult[HList]](JsSuccess(HNil))(merger)
}

combineJsResults(JsSuccess(1), JsSuccess("2"), JsSuccess(true))
```

Thank you very much for helping me understanding how to resolve this problem.

**EDIT**: I made some progress

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsError, JsSuccess}
import shapeless._

object combine extends Poly2 {
  def concatSuccess[L, R <: HList](l: JsSuccess[L], r: JsSuccess[R]): JsSuccess[L :: R] = JsSuccess(l.value :: r.value)

  implicit def successSuccess[L, R <: HList] = at[JsSuccess[L], JsSuccess[R]](concatSuccess)
  implicit def errorSuccess[R <: HList] = at[JsError, JsSuccess[R]]((l: JsError, r : JsSuccess[R]) => l)
  implicit val errorError = at[JsError, JsError](_ ++ _)
  implicit def successError[S] = at[JsSuccess[S], JsError]((l: JsSuccess[S], r: JsError) => r)
}

(JsSuccess(true) :: HNil).foldRight(JsSuccess(HNil))(combine)
(JsError("error") :: HNil).foldRight(JsSuccess(HNil))(combine)

val res1 = (JsSuccess(true) :: JsSuccess(1) :: HNil).foldRight(JsSuccess(HNil))(combine)
(JsError("error1") :: JsError("error2") :: HNil).foldRight(JsSuccess(HNil))(combine)
(JsSuccess(true) :: JsError("error2") :: HNil).foldRight(JsSuccess(HNil))(combine)
```

this code compiles, it successfully transforms a list of JsResult[_] into a JsResult[HList] now I need to be able to transform that HList to a tuple to pass it to the tupled method of a case class. 
I looked at the example involving the use of the Generic object but it doesn't compile because Generic[some case class].to method expect a Repr argument instead of a HList.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks